# SQL Server update query replace last character of a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a column name `source` which has values like `JBInfotech_CLC_4120_20160128`.

How do I update the last character to `7`. There are hundreds of records I want to update at the same time. Which is these records:

```
SELECT * FROM [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads] WHERE id <= 985 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This is permanently updating the record not select.

Comment: Always the same length?

Comment: Nope. those are different lengths but same last characters.

Comment: This is why you should always store distinct pieces of data in their own column.  If the application requires that you show them together, do that show them together.  However, you don't need to store them in a single column just because you show them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
  (
     col1 VARCHAR(100)
  )

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES      ('ABCDEF123'),
            ('JBInfotech_CLC_4120_20160128')

SELECT *
FROM   @table

UPDATE @table
SET    col1 = Stuff(col1, Len(col1), 1, '7')

SELECT *
FROM   @table
```

Comment: Thanks . Works fine. I just make UPDATE [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads] SET source = Stuff(source, Len(source), 1, '7')  WHERE id <= 985;

Comment: Welcome. Please select my answer if it best suits for you.

Comment: Yes will do, after the timer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
update [JBINFOTECH].[dbo].[leads]
Set [Source]=Concat(Left([Source],len([Source])-1), '7')
WHERE id <= 985
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE `leads` SET `source`= CONCAT(substring(source,CHAR_LENGTH(source) - 1),'7') WHERE id <= 985

Comment: Those double quotes will not do what you think they will. And anyway, this was already answered 1 hour before.